# Unable to enter Name with Spaces in C program?

Tags: c

This program asks for employee name, age and Salary. There is one slight problem and i don't know what this wrong. When i enter name without space or just the first name, then program works correctly but as soon as i enter full name with space. The program just skips some values without asking and jumps to other values. I know their is something wrong with scant of "worker[i].name" and i have tried %c too but with no success.

```
struct employee {

int pAge;
float salary;
char name[30];
};

int main(void) {

struct employee worker[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    printf("Enter Name of %d employee: ", (i+1));
    scanf(" %s", worker[i].name);

    printf("Enter Age of %d employee: ", (i+1));
    scanf("%d", &worker[i].pAge);

    printf("Enter Salary of %d employee: ", (i+1));
    scanf("%f", &worker[i].salary);
}
printf("\n");

printf("List of All workers\n\n");
printf( "Age\tSalary\t\tName\n");

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("%d\t%.2f\t\t%s\n", worker[i].pAge, worker[i].salary, worker[i].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect to know when the user is finished typing?

Comment: @SLaks When user press enter.

Comment: When do you want the next line of your code to run?

Comment: Is this not vulnerable to an overflow if the user’s name is longer than 29 characters…?

Comment: @SLaks When i press enter, i know that is also a blank space but isn't it different from the space?

Comment: @binki What should i do about it then?

Comment: @JohnBatistë Either dynamically allocate the name buffer using a function like [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) after which you would trim out the newline character or manually scan the input byte by byte to ensure you read no more than 29 bytes (is there a way to do this with `scanf()`?).

Comment: The `fgets` function is good for getting a whole line at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple just use this instead:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s", worker[i].name);
```

Comment: Any supporting documentation / citation / references / explanation?

Comment: Thanks its working but i quite didn't get it that why is it working. Anyways your help is appreciated.